# Python - Parse object index with multiple time zones

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing, timezone

Python Q. How to parse an object index in a data frame into its date, time, and time zone when it has multiple time zones?

The format is "YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS-HH:MM" where the right "HH:MM" is the timezone.

Example: Midnight Jan 1st, 2020 in Mountain Time, counting up:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
2020-01-01 01:00:00-07:00
2020-01-01 02:00:00-07:00
2020-01-01 04:00:00-06:00
```

I've got code that works for one time zone, but it breaks when a second timezone is introduced.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['year']= df['Date'].dt.year
df['month']= df['Date'].dt.month
df['month_n']= df['Date'].dt.month_name()
df['day']= df['Date'].dt.day
df['day_n']= df['Date'].dt.day_name()
df['h']= df['Date'].dt.hour
df['mn']= df['Date'].dt.minute
df['s']= df['Date'].dt.second
```

> ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc="True"

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`pandas.DataFrame.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead  :

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df_info = df['Date'].apply(lambda t: pd.Series({
    'date': t.date(),
    'year': t.year,
    'month': t.month,
    'month_n': t.strftime("%B"),
    'day': t.day,
    'day_n': t.strftime("%A"),
    'h': t.hour,
    'mn': t.minute,
    's': t.second,
}))

df = pd.concat([df, df_info], axis=1)
```

###### # Output :

```
print(df)

                                                    Date        date  year  month  month_n  day      day_n  h  mn  s
    col                                                                                                             
    2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00  2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00  2020-01-01  2020      1  January    1  Wednesday  0   0  0
    2020-01-01 01:00:00-07:00  2020-01-01 01:00:00-07:00  2020-01-01  2020      1  January    1  Wednesday  1   0  0
    2020-01-01 02:00:00-07:00  2020-01-01 02:00:00-07:00  2020-01-01  2020      1  January    1  Wednesday  2   0  0
    2020-01-01 04:00:00-06:00  2020-01-01 04:00:00-06:00  2020-01-01  2020      1  January    1  Wednesday  4   0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

@abokey 's answer is great if you aren't sure of the actual time zone or cannot work with UTC. However, you don't have the `dt` accessor and lose the performance of a "vectorized" approach.

So if you *can* use UTC or set a time zone (you just have UTC offset at the moment !), e.g. "America/Denver", all will work as expected:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'v': [999,999,999,999]},
                   index = ["2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00",
                            "2020-01-01 01:00:00-07:00",
                            "2020-01-01 02:00:00-07:00",
                            "2020-01-01 04:00:00-06:00"])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)

print(df.Date.dt.hour)
# 2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00     7
# 2020-01-01 01:00:00-07:00     8
# 2020-01-01 02:00:00-07:00     9
# 2020-01-01 04:00:00-06:00    10
# Name: Date, dtype: int64

# Note: hour changed since we converted to UTC !
```

***or***

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True).tz_convert("America/Denver")
print(df.Date.dt.hour)
# 2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00    0
# 2020-01-01 01:00:00-07:00    1
# 2020-01-01 02:00:00-07:00    2
# 2020-01-01 04:00:00-06:00    3
# Name: Date, dtype: int64
```